# Exchange 2007 Mailbox Permissions (Without Powershell Cmdlets)

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

Is there a way to grant a user "Full Mailbox Access" to a users mailbox without using the Exchange Management Shell components?

Wanting to grant the access remotely but without having to deploy PowerShell and the EMS components. I'm working in C# (.Net 3.5) with Exchange Server 2007 SP1.

Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of responses it appears there's no way to do this, will look at using the Powershell cmdlets through a ASP application.